# Подключением библиотек от Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, c++

Работал с `Visual studio`.
Купил `Mac`.
Есть способ установки другого софта с подключением библиотек от `visual studio`?

Comment: [VS in MacOS][1]

[1]: http://weblogs.asp.net/latishsehgal/archive/2009/08/15/working-with-visual-studio-on-a-mac.aspx

Comment: хотелось бы избежать виртуальных машин

Comment: VMWare хорошо работает, и на номальном железе практически не будет видно никакой разницы. Благо у Mac с этим все в порядке.

Comment: спрашивается, а нахрена ты мак то покупал ?

Comment: @KoCaTKo возможно, ответом на этот вопрос является заголовок данной темы)

Comment: @Стив, Вы на правильном пути. Осталось отказатся и от библиотек VS.

Comment: @DreamChild ну в принципе да…… для чего думать головой, главное же понтануться

Comment: П давайте разведем здась холивар и будем поливать друг-друга! Или, возможно, вопрос поставлен непонятно...

Comment: ну заметьте не я это предложил )) да что тут отвечать то ? пусть чувак ставит либо виртуалку, либо wine, либо windows как 2 ОС через буткамп … все… других вариантов попросту нет

Comment: Пусть ТС ответит: зачем ему это нужно? Запустить в макосе виндовскую программу? Или просто не хочется уходить со знакомой среды разработки?

Answer (score 1):

Виртуалка без вариантов...

Можно попробовать использовать последнюю из возможных рабочую версию *wine*, но вот [здесь](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=22306&iTestingId=66628), что у нее большие проблемы(по крайней мере в 2010).

Comment: Можно винду поставить как вторую систему. С вин7 проблем никаких.

Comment: @Zelta, но зачем тогда мак нужен...
Можно просто Дистр GNU/Linux поставить на обычный комп.